# Comparing datetime.time and pd.TimeStamp in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataset with `pd.TimeStamp` data contained in a `CRASH TIME` column, e.g. `Timestamp('2017-06-26 22:00:00')`. I created a new column called `SUNRISE` which contains `datetime` data, e.g. `datetime.time(5, 26, 50, 135154)`.

I'd like to compare the times of `CRASH TIME` and `SUNRISE` to determine if the times in `CRASH TIME` are before or after sunrise. When I try to do this via the following:

```
df['DAYTIME'] = 0
after_sunrise = df['CRASH TIME'] > df['SUNRISE']
df.loc[after_sunrise == True, 'DAYTIME'] = 1
```

I receive an error: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'datetime.time'`. How can I compare `pd.TimeStamp` and `datetime.time`? I know I can perform an `apply()` with the techniques found [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/timestamp-datetime), but I feel like there's a more pandas-oriented method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Series.dt.time` method to convert the pandas `TimeStamps` into `datetime.time` object and then other things are straightforward:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import time

#Create fake dataset
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["CRASH TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(['2017-06-26 22:00:00', '2017-06-27 21:50:00'])
df["SUNRISE"] = [time(22, 26, 50, 135154), time(21, 26, 49, 135154)]
print(df.head())

print("CRASH TIME element type:", type(df["CRASH TIME"][0]))

print("SUNRISE element type:", type(df["SUNRISE"][0]))

df["CRASH TIME"] = df["CRASH TIME"].dt.time

print("CRASH TIME element type:", type(df["CRASH TIME"][0]))
```

Output->

```
           CRASH TIME          SUNRISE
0 2017-06-26 22:00:00  22:26:50.135154
1 2017-06-27 21:50:00  21:26:49.135154
CRASH TIME element type: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
SUNRISE element type: <class 'datetime.time'>
CRASH TIME element type: <class 'datetime.time'>
```

[image]