# Same Pandas timestamp objects returns False when compared for eqality

Tags: pandas, time-series, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe with a time_stamp column with max value "Timestamp('2019-12-30 23:50:00+0000', tz='UTC')". I created another ts object from a string with exact same values but they are not equal. No idea why that is happening.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U8zV.png)

I tried to remove the UTC but could not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please edit your post so as to share all [code, data and error tracebacks as **text, not images**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
To share dataframes: output of `print(df)` or `print(df.to_dict())`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Md Zahidul Islam,

This error can happen for a few reasons because timestamp are sometimes a bit tricky and non-intuitive. Even if two timestamps look the same when printed, they could have differences.

As far as i know there is couple of things to check:

1. First check the type of your column with `df['time_stamp'].dtypes` to make sure is not datetime or simple object or other.
2. The timestamp might have microsecond values that are not displayed, check with `Timestamp.nanosecond`.
3. Check internal representation. Look at the class details of [Timestamp in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html). For example test with the `asm8` attribute that return your timestamp into numpy datetime64
4. Check if your timestamp has timezone information with the `tz` attribute, here a [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.tz.html#pandas.Timestamp.tz)

It's all i know and i let the community adding item or discuss my list :)

But in the end if i understand well you want to compare timestamp.
There are several ways to do this but here is a list of posts on stackoverflow that should help you :

- [How to compare two timestamps in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378977/how-to-compare-two-timestamps-in-python)
- [Comparing datetime.time and pd.TimeStamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697493/comparing-datetime-time-and-pd-timestamp-in-python)

Have a nice day,
Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I made a stupid mistake instead of using 2019 I was using 2109

Comment: And now you know how to use it easily :)
Have a nice day